# Parámetros ,variable locales en metodo?

Tags: java

Hola amigos disculpen una pregunta en java estoy estudiando:

Y me pregunto es?

Es posible pasar una variable local de un metodo a otro metodo?

Soy novato en los metodos en java

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que te refieres a pasar una variable por *referencia* con enviar una variable local de un método a otro. Por ejemplo:

```
public void valor(int num){
   num += 1;
}
```

Al ejecutar la función valor desde el main y luego imprimir la variable num se observa que su valor no cambió. Esto es debido a que los tipos de dato primitivos (int, char, double, etc) no se pasan a través de la función, sino que se genera una copia que existe en el scope de la misma. Por lo tanto para valores primitivos no es posible pasar "la variable" pero sí su valor. Con objetos es distinto, por ejemplo:

```
public class Test{

    static class Foo{
        int a;
        public Foo(int a){
            this.a = a;
        }
    }

    public static void f(Foo foo){
        foo.a = 10;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Foo foo = new Foo(1);
        System.out.println(foo.a);
        f(foo);
        System.out.println(foo.a);
    }
}
```

El código anterior imprime 1 y 10, esto es debido a que no se realiza una copia del objeto, sino que se pasa su *referencia*, al modificar el objeto internamente si se refleja el cambio. Sin embargo, es importante notar que al cambiar la referencia y apuntar a un objeto nuevo la referencia original no se cambiará.

Answer (score 1):

Respondiendo a tu pregunta:

- Cuando "pasas" una variable de un OBJETO a un método, siempre pasas la referencia a éste, pero no pasas el objeto en sí.
- Cuando "pasas" una variable de un tipo de dato primitivo, siempre creas una copia de este.

Trate de ejemplificar y detallar en el código. Espero te sirva.

Si lo corres tendrías:

```
    Valor A: Este es mi valor A
    Valor B: Este es mi valor B
    Valor A: Otro valor A
    Valor B: Otro valor B
    9
    8
    9
```

Código:

```
    public class PasandoVariables{
            private String valorA;
            private String valorB;

            //Asigna valor a A
            public void setValorA(String valorA){
                    this.valorA=valorA;//Uso de this para evitar confusiones
            }
            //Asigna valor a B
            public void setValorB(String otroValorB){
                    valorB=otroValorB;
            }

            //Simple impresion de valores actuales del objeto PasandoVariables
            private void imprimeValores(){
                    System.out.println("Valor A: "+valorA);
                    System.out.println("Valor B: "+valorB);
            }

            //Aqui inicia todo
            public static void main(String[] args){
                    //Aqui crea un objeto en memoria y lo asigna a la variable pv
                    PasandoVariables pv = new PasandoVariables();

                    //Aqui paso el objeto al metodo estatico, donde pv es mi "variable local"
                    actualiza(pv);

                    pv.imprimeValores();

                    //Cambio los valores para confirmar que es el mismo objeto
                    pv.setValorA("Otro valor A");
                    pv.setValorB("Otro valor B");

                    pv.imprimeValores();

                    //Creando variable primitiva
                    int variablePrimitiva = 9;

                    //Imprime valor actual
                    System.out.println(variablePrimitiva);

                    //Paso la variable primitiva
                    actualiza(variablePrimitiva);

                    //No afecto el valor final, porque el metodo anteior creo una copia
                    //Esto solo pasa con datos primitivos, no con objetos
                    System.out.println(variablePrimitiva);
            }

            //Este metodo "sabe" cual es el objeto a modificar, porque tiene la referencia del metodo main
            public static void actualiza(PasandoVariables pv){
                    pv.setValorA("Este es mi valor A");
                    pv.setValorB("Este es mi valor B");
            }

            //Se genera una copia del dato primitivo
            public static void actualiza(int variablePrimitiva){
                    variablePrimitiva = 8;
                    //Imprime el valor actual, para que confirmes que se cambio localmente
                    System.out.println(variablePrimitiva);
            }
    }
```

PD: me sentí extraño respondiendo en español :p

Answer (score 0):

La "regla" de los parámetros *(no existe, me lo acabo de inventar)* es que, cualquier cosa que puedas pasar como parámetro, puede pasar como parámetro en la llamada a otra función, imagina el siguiente bloque:

```
int Suma10(int x) {
    return x + 10;
}
```

Y que tienes la siguiente función con una variable local:

```
int Algo() {
    int n = 4; // Variable local n

    if (n >= 4) 
        n = Suma10(n); // El valor de n ahora es 14.

    n = Suma10(Suma10(n)); // Es igual a 14 + 10 + 10 = 34

    return n;
}
```

Lo que nos deja dicho, que funciones que retornen el mismo tipo de dato que el parámetro especificado y variables globales y locales del mismo tipo, pueden ser pasadas como parámetro de una función.

¡Espero te haya ayudado!